# Starting an Activity from a Button inside a fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am looking to click a button inside a fragment and an Activity. The destination activity "GoogleMaps.class" is already inside my manifest and been used inside an onClick in another Activity so that is not the problem. I have tried the following code;

```
private void onClick_nci()

 {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GoogleMaps.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }
```

I have also tried every answer that is on StackOverflow and have not found a solution, have you any idea, thanks.

MyFragmentB.

```
package com.test.finalproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyFragmentB extends Fragment implements OnInitListener, OnClickListener{

private TextToSpeech tts;
private Button btnSpeak;
private TextView txtText;
Button nci;

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);




  nci = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.nci);

  tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);

  btnSpeak = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

  txtText = (TextView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }



    });
    return myFragmentView;
    }
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Don't forget to shutdown!
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }



private void onClick_nci(View v)

 {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GoogleMaps.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    }







private void speakOut() {

    String text = txtText.getText().toString();

    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




}
```

LogCat.

12-09 17:18:42.046: I/Choreographer(11466): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-09 17:18:45.246: D/AndroidRuntime(11466): Shutting down VM
12-09 17:18:45.246: W/dalvikvm(11466): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c64da0)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): Process: com.test.finalproject, PID: 11466
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick_nci(View) in the activity class com.test.finalproject.Tabs for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'nci'
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3956)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClick_nci [class android.view.View]
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3949)
12-09 17:18:45.256: E/AndroidRuntime(11466):    ... 11 more

Comment: What happens? Are you sure that code is getting called? If you know it is getting called, does your LogCat say anything?

Comment: Have you used setOnClickListener or onClick in xml? Can you put the full code?

Comment: are you calling the method? or do you expect android to know that onClick method??

Comment: I'll add the code now

Comment: Added the code and Logcat

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure, you're code is getting called?

Try this to start your intent with the parent Activity context:

```
getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

the `startActivity` method is for `Activity` class. then you should have an `Activity` object to call that function. in your `Activity` you can use `startActivity` because `this` refers to an `Activity` object but in `Fragment` class, `this` refers to `Fragment` object and there is no method `StartActivity` in `Fragment` class. you should use your `Activity` object or use an `interface` to communicate between your `Fragment` and your `Activity`.

here is an example :

```
private void onClick_nci()

 {
    Intent intent = new Intent(yourFragmentClass.this.getActivity(), GoogleMaps.class);
    yourFragmentClass.this.getActivity().startActivity(intent);

  }
```

Comment: @JamesCgrave see above ans, you have to use `CurrentActivity.this`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start new Activity from fragment then you need activity object/reference (getActivity()) to create Intent & call StartActivity() method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GoogleMaps.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure button has onClick attribute in xml.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:onClick="onClick_nci" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved my problem, Ive been looking at the screen too long and i Couldnt see the problem, thank you.